# (Vue.js) How to change 'background-image' when access the page

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I want to change 'background-image' when i access the page.

```
export default {
  created () {
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.background = "url('../assets/background-blur.png') center"
  }
} //Login.vue
```

The structure of the file is
**src

└assets

  　└background-blur.png

└views

  　└Login.vue**

instead of 'url', the color works normally.
For example

```
export default {
  created () {
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.background = 'blue'
  }
} //Login.vue
```

I don't know how to solve a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `require` as follows :

```
export default {
  created () {
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.background = `url(${require('../assets/background-blur.png')}) center`
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll try that when I get home. Thank you.